# General setup for ASP.net REST webapi

Tags: asp.net, rest

I am currently building a REST webapi. Right now I am wondering if this design is in the right direction.

Firstly, I am using entity framework. I like to call the items in the database DbItems. The items returned by the api are called DtoItems. Just to keep them apart in this example.

### Mapping

I use mappers that are added as services to the project. When mapping items, I can add a configuration to map items to certain depth. Next, the mappers don't create items, but only copy parameters. This is on purpose, so I can update existing database objects. Although the code could be simplified if this wasn't the case. (Now that I am writing this, I guess EF will solve this if I update an item with an existing Key or Id.)

Example of a mapper:

```
public class ProjectItemDbMapper : IMapper<ProjectItemDb, ProjectItemDbDto>
{
    private readonly IMapper<User, UserDto> _userMapper;
    private readonly AppDbContext _context;

    public ProjectItemDbMapper(IMapper<User, UserDto> userMapper, AppDbContext context)
    {
        _userMapper = userMapper;
        _context = context;
    }


    public async Task MapToDb(ProjectItemDb dbItem, ProjectItemDbDto dtoItem, MapperOptions options)
    {
        if (dtoItem.Id != null) dbItem.Id = dtoItem.Id.Value;
        if (dtoItem.Title != null) dbItem.Title = dtoItem.Title;
        if (dtoItem.Created != null) dbItem.Created = dtoItem.Created.Value;

        if (dtoItem.Parent?.Id != null)
            dbItem.Parent = await _context.ProjectItemDbs.FindAsync(dtoItem.Parent.Id);

        if (dtoItem.CreatedByUser?.Id != null)
            dbItem.CreatedByUser = await _context.Users.FindAsync(dtoItem.CreatedByUser.Id);

    }

    public async Task MapToDto(ProjectItemDb dbItem, ProjectItemDbDto dtoItem, MapperOptions options)
    {
        options.Depth--;
        dtoItem.Id = dbItem.Id;
        dtoItem.Title = dbItem.Title;
        dtoItem.Created = dbItem.Created;

        if(options.Depth > 0)   //Only map children if required
        {
            if (dbItem.CreatedByUser != null)
            {
                await _userMapper.MapToDto(dbItem.CreatedByUser, dtoItem.CreatedByUser, options);
            }
            
            if (dbItem.Parent != null)
            {
                await _MapToDto(dbItem.Parent, dtoItem.Parent, options);
            }
        } 
        else if(options.Depth == 0)
        {
            //TODO: Only load the Id of the object. (Make this a setting in MapperOptions)
        }
        options.Depth++;
    }
}
```

### Repositories

The next problem I have is when deleting objects. When deleting objects, I also need to delete the children. Or throw an error if the children should be manually deleted. Or only detach the link between the objects. This is something I want to manage in repositories. (By lack of a better name) The repository works with the DBEntities. Since the repositories are more or less the same, I am considering making a generic one where the methods can be overridden.

In this example, I also delete child objects when deleting a projectItem. The reason I want to register these as services is, so I can use dependency injection to get other repositories if I want to delete the User for example.

```
public class GenericRepository<ProjectItem> : IRepository<ProjectItem>
    where ProjectItem : class
{
    protected readonly AppDbContext _context;

    public GenericRepository(AppDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));
    }

    public async Task<ProjectItem?> CreateAsync(ProjectItem entity)
    {
        if (entity == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(entity));

        _context.Set<ProjectItem>().Add(entity);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return entity;
    }

    public async Task<bool> DeleteAsync(int id)
    {
        var entity = await _context.Set<ProjectItem>().FindAsync(id);
        if (entity == null)
            return false;
        
        var children = entity.Children.ToList();
        foreach(var child in children)
            await DeleteAsync(child.id);

        _context.Set<ProjectItem>().Remove(entity);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return true;
    }

    public async Task<IEnumerable<ProjectItem>> GetAllAsync(string? filter, string orderBy, int page, int pageSize)
    {
        IQueryable<ProjectItem> query = _context.Set<ProjectItem>();

        // Apply filters to the query (you need to implement filter logic)

        // Apply ordering to the query if orderBy is provided
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(orderBy))
        {
            // You need to implement your custom ordering logic here
            // Example: query = query.OrderBy(orderBy);
        }

        // Apply paging to the query
        if (pageSize > 0)
        {
            int skip = (page - 1) * pageSize;
            query = query.Skip(skip).Take(pageSize);
        }

        return await query.ToListAsync();
    }

    public async Task<ProjectItem?> GetByIdAsync(int id)
    {
        return await _context.Set<ProjectItem>().FindAsync(id);
    }

    public async Task<ProjectItem?> UpdateAsync(int id, ProjectItem entity)
    {
        if (entity == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(entity));

        var existingEntity = await _context.Set<ProjectItem>().FindAsync(id);
        if (existingEntity == null)
            return null;

        // Update the existing entity properties with the values from the entity
        // Make sure to implement this update logic
        // Example: existingEntity.Property = entity.Property;

        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return existingEntity;
    }
}
```

### Controllers

An example of a controller to check how all this is used:

```
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class ProjectItemsController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IRepository<DbItem> _repositoryContext;
    private readonly AppDbContext _context;
    private readonly IMapper<DbItem, DtoItem> _mapper;
    private readonly UserManager _userManager;

    public ProjectItemsController(IRepository<DbItem> repositoryContext, AppDbContext context, IMapper<DbItem, DtoItem> mapper, UserManager userManager)
    {
        _repositoryContext = repositoryContext;
        _context = context;
        _mapper = mapper;
        _userManager = userManager;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("GetById")]
    virtual public async Task<ActionResult<DtoItem>> GetById(int id)
    {
        DbItem? dbItem = await _repositoryContext.GetByIdAsync(id);
        if (dbItem == null)
            return NotFound();
        DtoItem dtoItem = Activator.CreateInstance<DtoItem>();
        await _mapper.MapToDto(dbItem, dtoItem, new MapperOptions { Depth = 1 });
        return Ok(dtoItem);
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("GetAll")]
    virtual public async Task<ActionResult<DtoItem[]>> GetAll(string? filters, string? order, int? pageNo, int? pageSize)
    {
        var dbItems = await _repositoryContext.GetAllAsync(filters, order ?? "Id", pageNo ?? 1, pageSize ?? 25);
        List<DtoItem> dtoItems = new List<DtoItem>();

        foreach (var dbItem in dbItems)
        {
            DtoItem dtoItem = Activator.CreateInstance<DtoItem>();
            await _mapper.MapToDto(dbItem, dtoItem, new MapperOptions { Depth = 1 });
            dtoItems.Add(dtoItem);
        }

        return Ok(dtoItems);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [Route("Create")]
    virtual public async Task<ActionResult<DtoItem>> Create(DtoItem dtoItem)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            DbItem dbItem = Activator.CreateInstance<DbItem>();
            await _mapper.MapToDb(dbItem, dtoItem, new MapperOptions { Depth = 1 });
            dbItem.CreatedByUser = await _userManager.GetUser(User);
            dbItem.Created = DateTime.Now;

            var newDbItem = await _repositoryContext.CreateAsync(dbItem);
            DtoItem newDtoItem = Activator.CreateInstance<DtoItem>();
            await _mapper.MapToDto(newDbItem, newDtoItem, new MapperOptions { Depth = 1 });
            return CreatedAtAction("GetById", newDtoItem);
        }
        return BadRequest();
    }

    [HttpPatch]
    [Route("Patch")]
    virtual public async Task<ActionResult<DtoItem>> Patch(int id, DtoItem dtoItem)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (await _repositoryContext.GetByIdAsync(id) is DbItem dbItem)
            {
                if (dbItem.CreatedByUser?.Id != _userManager.GetUser(User).Id)
                    return BadRequest();

                await _mapper.MapToDb(dbItem, dtoItem, new MapperOptions { Depth = 1 });
                var newDbItem = await _repositoryContext.CreateAsync(dbItem);

                DtoItem newDtoItem = Activator.CreateInstance<DtoItem>();
                await _mapper.MapToDto(newDbItem, newDtoItem, new MapperOptions { Depth = 1 });
                return Ok(newDtoItem);
            }
            return NotFound();
        }
        return BadRequest();
    }

    [HttpDelete]
    [Route("Delete")]
    virtual public async Task<IActionResult> Delete(int id)
    {
        var result = await _repositoryContext.DeleteAsync(id);
        if (result)
            return Ok();
        return NoContent();
    }
}
```

### Program.cs

How I register the services.

```
builder.Services
    .AddScoped<IRepository<User>, UserRepository>()
    .AddScoped<IMapper<User, UserDto>, UserMapper>()
    .AddScoped<IRepository<ProjectItemDb>, ProjectItemDbRepository>()
    .AddScoped<IMapper<ProjectItemDb, ProjectItemDbDto>, ProjectItemDbMapper>();
```